# Is it possible to check the code of a vector design?

Tags: svg, vector, eps

I understand that all vector drawings (even others) are made of codes. I was wondering if its possible to check the code of the same. For instance, if I have a rectangle in .svg or .eps format, how do I check the code that makes this rectangle ?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it in a text editor?

For instance, [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg) should look like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

 <title>SVG Logo</title>

 <a xlink:href="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/" target="_parent"
 xlink:title="W3C SVG Working Group home page">

   <rect
    id="background"
    fill="#FF9900"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    rx="4"
    ry="4"/>

...
```